# Which biography of Sri Ramakrishna mentions the visit of a Ramanandi Vaishnava to the Dakshineshwar Temple?

Tags: history, rama, identification-request, ramakrishna

According to [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/vRzGoCzCGU0), a Ramanandi Vaishnava in Ayodhya had received the vision of Rama in his dream oncr where the Lord says He has taken incarnated in Bengal as Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa. As a result, this monk walked barefoot for days to the Dakshineshwar Temple where Sri Ramakrishna resided. Unfortunately, he was too late. Sri Ramakrishna had passed away days ago. As a result, the monk is said to gone to the Panchavati where he began to weep for days. Then, according to the video, the Ramanandi monk saw Sri Ramakrishna emerging from the Ganges who soon fed the monk payasam.

In which biography of Sri Ramakrishna, is this story mentioned?

Update: This story was narrated by Sri Ramakrishna's nephew, Ram Lal Chattopadhay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [read story with more context here](https://vimokshananda.com/2011/03/06/wishfulfilled-dream/)

Story is in "Ramakrishna as we saw Him" by Swami Chetanananda

As you said, it is a reminiscence by Ramlal Chattopadhyay (Sri Ramakrishna's nephew)

is on page 57, 3rd edition (2008)

[Here you have link](https://archive.org/stream/RamakrishnaAsWeSawHimSwamiChetananandaR.K.Mutt/Ramakrishna%20As%20We%20Saw%20Him%20Swami%20Chetanananda%20R.K.%20Mutt_djvu.txt)

> After Sri Ramakrishna's Passing Away
>
> A young Ramait monk [a worshiper of Ramachandra] in Ayodhya  had a
>   vision that God had again incarnated on earth, somewhere m the  east.
>   In order to see him, the monk started on foot eastward from  Ayodhya.
>   When he reached Bengal he heard that there was a great saint  named
>   Sri Ramakrishna near Calcutta. He finally found Dakshineswar  after a
>   long search and asked someone, "Where is Ramakrishna Para-  mahamsa?"
>   The people of the Kali temple told him that the Master had  just
>   passed away a few days before. Hearing this heartbreaking news.
>
> the monk exclaimed: "What! He passed away? I have come from Ayo-  dhya
>   on foot [nearly a thousand miles] just to see him. I went through  so
>   much hardship to get here and he has left the body!" The young monk 
>   began to sob.
>
> The manager of the Kali temple offered him some food from the  temple
>   store but he refused it. He went to the Panchavati and stayed  there
>   for two or three days without eating. One night Sri Ramakrishna 
>   appeared before him and said: "You have not eaten anything for several
>   days. I have brought this pudding for ycu. Please eat it." He fed the
>   monk  and disappeared.
>
> Thi next morning I went to the Panchavati and found the monk full  of
>   joy. I asked: "What happened? You were so unhappy yesterday. Why  are
>   you so cheerful toda)?" Then he told me everything. He even  showed me
>   the earthen bowl in which the Master had brought the  pudding. [Ramlal
>   preserved that bowl for a long time , but somehow it was  destroyed.]
>   **(Udbodhan , vol. 49, no. 10)**
>
> **[From: Sri Ramakrishna O Antaranga Prasanga, by Kamal Krishna Mittra  (Dakshineswar: K. K. Mittra), 1932; Udbodhan (Calcutta: Udbodhan Of¬ 
>   fice), vol. 49, no. 10,1947]**

Comment: Do we have the name of this monk?